# Accumulate results of each intermediate recursive call using F# and Bloomberg API

Tags: recursion, f#, bloomberg, blpapi

I'm using the B-Pipe API to request financial securities data from Bloomberg. Large requests are divided into small groups and returned as `PARTIAL_RESPONSE` with the final response being `RESPONSE`. The recursive `handleSingleEvent` function recurses until a final `RESPONSE` is returned by `reqEventQueue.NextEvent()`.

My problem is that only the final `RESPONSE` group of securities are returned. The intermediate `PARTIAL_RESPONSE` groups are not returned by the function. However, these `PARTIAL_RESPONSE` groups are received from Bloomberg.

I'm thinking I might need some accumulator parameters or should use something similar to List.collect, but I don't have a clue how to get started.

```
// list<Request> * EventQueue * Session -> list<list<string>>
let handleEvents (requests: Request list, reqEventQueue: EventQueue, session: Session) =
      let rec handleSingleEvent (request: Request) =
        try
          let eventObj = reqEventQueue.NextEvent()

          match eventObj.Type with          
          | Event.EventType.PARTIAL_RESPONSE ->
            processReferenceResponseEvent eventObj
            |> makeJson
            |> ignore

            handleSingleEvent request
          | Event.EventType.RESPONSE -> processReferenceResponseEvent eventObj |> makeJson
          | _ -> processMiscEvents eventObj |> makeJson
        with
        | ex -> failwithf "%s" ex.Message

      List.map (fun request -> handleSingleEvent request) requests
```

**Update**
I made edits, but now code seems to enter infinite recursion.

```
let handleEvents (requests: Request list, reqEventQueue: EventQueue, session: Session)  =
      let rec handleSingleEvent (request: Request) : seq<list<string>> =
        seq {
          
              let eventObj = reqEventQueue.NextEvent()

              match eventObj.Type with
              | Event.EventType.REQUEST_STATUS -> yield processMiscEvents eventObj |> makeJson
              | Event.EventType.ADMIN -> yield processAdminEvent eventObj |> makeJson
              | Event.EventType.AUTHORIZATION_STATUS -> yield processAuthEvent eventObj session |> makeJson
              | Event.EventType.PARTIAL_RESPONSE ->
                yield processReferenceResponseEvent eventObj
                |> makeJson
                yield! handleSingleEvent request
              | Event.EventType.RESPONSE -> yield processReferenceResponseEvent eventObj |> makeJson
              | _ -> yield processMiscEvents eventObj |> makeJson
        } |> ignore
        handleSingleEvent request
      List.map (fun request -> handleSingleEvent request) requests
```

Comment: I ain't sure if this helpful, but recursion that yields intermediate results is called corecursion and commonly handled by `scan` family of functions, like `List.scan`

Comment: @JL0PD In this particular case I wasn't able to use any collection function such as List.scan or List.collect because I was unable to get a list of Event objects. The Bloomberg API seems to stream data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Bloomberg API, but this is a fairly common pattern. I think the easiest way to handle it is to generate a sequence of JSON strings recursively, using `yield` to process the current event and `yield!` to process the remainder of the queue recursively. That way you don't have to worry about accumulating the results manually. So something like this:

```ml
let rec loop () : seq<string> =   // assumption: makeJson has type _ -> string
    seq {
        let eventObj = reqEventQueue.NextEvent()
        match eventObj.Type with          
            | Event.EventType.PARTIAL_RESPONSE ->
                yield processReferenceResponseEvent eventObj
                    |> makeJson
                yield! loop ()
            | Event.EventType.RESPONSE ->
                yield processReferenceResponseEvent eventObj
                    |> makeJson
            | _ ->
                yield processMiscEvents eventObj
                    |> makeJson
    }
loop ()
```

There are some other issues in your code that I haven't attempted to address, such as the fact that the `request` and `session` values aren't used at all. I assume you can fix that easily enough.